# Insert data if previous column contains data

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I'm trying to think of a way where I can have a Powershell script check an Excel or CSV file, read the last column and then insert a static data for each row that has data. 
For example this is the original file:

```
| Id  | Price   | Description                     |
|-----|---------|---------------------------------|
| 33  | 878.35  | C2 Flush Casement               |
| 52  | 1111.69 | DS2-L101-T102_L                 |
| 71  | 875.75  | C2 Flush Casement               |
```

I would like to add the Quote number (Which I can get from the file name):

```
| Id | Price   | Description       | Quote |
|----|---------|-------------------|-------|
| 33 | 878.35  | C2 Flush Casement | Q1234 |
| 52 | 1111.69 | DS2-L101-T102_L   | Q1234 |
| 71 | 875.75  | C2 Flush Casement | Q1234 |
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Import-Csv` to read and parse the data, then create the new column with `Select-Object` and write to a new CSV file with `Export-Csv`:

```bsh
Import-Csv path\to\file.csv |Select-Object *,@{Name='Quote';Expression={if($_.Description -ne ''){'Q1234'}}} |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: My word, of course! I think messing around with SSIS and the like ruined my thoughts!